# How many of the integers are multiples of $10$ or $9$ but not a multiple of $90$?

Tags: combinatorics

Good evening, dear people! Who can help me with this job?

Among $410$ integers, $237$ are divisible by $10$, $137$ are multiples of $9$, $53$ are multiples of $100$, $111$ are multiples of $90$, $49$ are multiples of $900$. To determine how many of them are multiples of $10$ or $9$ but not a multiple of $90$.

Comment: do you mean "among 410 integers, 237 are divisible by 10, .."  ?

Comment: Please choose a more descriptive title.

Comment: I mean, just numbers 410, 237 multiples of 10 and so on..

Comment: Please check that my edits have not changed the question you wish to ask.

Comment: All is well, the issue has not changed

Answer (score 2):

Ok so I assume you mean there are 410 numbers in total an 237 are multiples of 10 and 137 are multiples of 9 so this gives $237+137$ numbers which are multiples of 10 or 9 BUT, those numbers which are multiples of both 9 and 10 have been counted twice, so the final answer should be $237+137-2(111)$.

Comment: And the numbers that are multiples of 100 and multiples of 900 are not taken into account?

Comment: No, I think that information is not relevant, at least as I have understood the question.